# FluentNhibernate, map class to multiple tables

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

Consider class A, B and C, both A and B has a collection of Cs. I want to map these collections to different tables, so I have table A_C and B_C. I try to do:

```
public class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{    
    Public AMap()
    { 
       Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
       HasMany(x => x.Cs).Table("A_C"); 
    }  
}

public class BMap : ClassMap<B>
{    
    Public BMap()
    { 
       Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
       HasMany(x => x.Cs).Table("B_C"); 
    }  
}

public class CMap : ClassMap<C>
{    
    Public CMap()
    { 
       Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    }  
}
```

..(with some extra properties), but it still creates just a single table of name "C". So what is the correct way to this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say go ahead and make your separate tables (on your own without using schema export) and properly configure your mappings the way you know they should work. NHibernate should figure things out so long as you've configured things correctly. You might have to tell it the name of the key column to join on. You can still use schema export to generate the other tables. After it's finished, go behind NHibernate and add your extra table.

```
public class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{    
    Public AMap()
    { 
       // ...
       HasMany(x => x.Cs).Table("A_C").KeyColumn("TheNameOfA'sPrimaryKeyColumn"); 
    }  
}

public class BMap : ClassMap<B>
{    
    Public BMap()
    { 
       // ...
       HasMany(x => x.Cs).Table("B_C").KeyColumn("TheNameOfB'sPrimaryKeyColumn"); 
    }  
}
```

NHibernate should do the joins properly. Let me know if it doesn't. Also, if you're dealing with a composite key and need help with that, let me know.

Comment: You won't need to specify the KeyColumn if you're accepting the deafults from NHibernate. It'll just figure it out. Something like A_Id, and B_Id. That's normally how it generates column names for foreign keys.

Comment: Oh, so to understand correct; It's simply not possible to get the tables auto-generated from the mappings, and neither by schema export when using custom table names?

Comment: Well...that I'm not sure of. It should actually be working. Why it's not and what additional configuration is required? I have no idea. But looks like the above setup should definitely get it to generate the separate tables. The thing about schema export is that it's kind of like a one time thing. Once it generates your database, you'll want to keep a copy of that script. It's a convenience thing because you'll always get a script that accurately reflects the latest version of your data model when you do indeed decide to use it. But as long as your tables aren't changing, you're good.

Comment: So I'd say just let it do it's thing as best it can, then tweak it to your liking. Once you're done, save the script and you won't need to generate a new one until your data model changes. In addition to that, you can script out the table that it's not generating into its own script. Then once the tool is done, run the script to generate the other table. It'll take the push of a button (F5) and you'll be done. Now you of course don't want to have to introduce this extra manual step in the process, but if you have to, then so be it.

Comment: Basically where I'm going wit this is that if no one else can figure out why the export tool isn't generating that extra table, you're alternative isn't a bad one at all. But yea, it'd be nice if the tool just figured out what the hell to do. Very puzzling as to why it won't generate your table. At any rate, good luck my friend.

Comment: :) Thanks for advising a way out. But I really hope someone can tell me if this actually should work or not. I do a lot of changes, so it's a pain to write custom scripts all the time if not needed.

Comment: Alright. Kool. If I can think of something that's missing or that could help, I'll let you know. Hopefully the others can chime in as well. I'd also advise upgrading to latest version of Fluent and trying there as well. We found a bug in 3.0 that forced us to upgrade to 3.2 and things worked afterwards. Nevermind my "other end of relationship comment". I just deleted it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "other end of relationship", it's uni-directional entity relationships. I added all my maps above, maybe it's clearer.